# maximum sum of adjacent path down a triangle

Tags: python

I'm working on the following challenge:

https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/89/

My solution:

```
import sys
test_cases = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
sum_track=0
index_track = 0
for test in test_cases:
    test = test.split()
    test = [int(x) for x in test]
    max_num =  max([test[max([0,index_track])],test[min([len(test)-1,index_track+1])]])
    print "adding " +str(max_num) # this line helps "track" my path through the triangle
    sum_track+= max_num
    index_track = test.index(max_num)

test_cases.close()

print sum_track
```

For reference, this is the "triangle" being tested against:

http://www.yodlecareers.com/puzzles/triangle.txt

I'm getting 665321 as the sum, which is incorrect. I've tried checking the steps my code above has printed out against the input file and it seemed correct for the first 10 lines, obviously I'm not going to go through the whole thing by hand though. Has anyone worked on this challenge before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a triangle like this:

```
       1
    2     3
99     4     5
```

Your algorithm will "greedily" follow the largest number it sees and end up finding `1+3+5`.  Clearly this is not the biggest sum, as it ignores the obvious `99` in the triangle!

Comment: ah...I seem to have totally misunderstood the question. Multiple paths will have to be evaluated. Thank you.

Comment: @V_TS Not quite every path... just certain ones.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple enough and can be done using dynamic programming. But you will have to start evaluating from the leaves (row 4 in the example), not the root node, and work backwards. So the inverted triangle is

```
0 7 1 5
4 6 8
9 6
5
```

Now solve by the recursion,
`f(row,col) = max(f(row-1,col), f(row-1,col+1))` with the boundary condition `f(0, col) = value(0, col)`. Terminate on final row

Comment: Why is working backwards necessary? It should also be sufficient to work from the root down.

Comment: mostly for space efficiency. If you work backwards, you need to store no more than 2 rows at any time

Comment: And if you work top-down, you have to compute the max value over each of the leaves, where this is implicitly done when working bottom-up. Good call.